# Okhttp asking to approve connection via dialog box want to make silent

Tags: web, service, okhttp, silent

I am using latest okhttp and when using at home it connects just fine. Inside a company it displays dialog box for approval to connect to a server. I do not want the user to see that dialog box just connect silently like it does for me at home. How do I get it to do that? I used httpclient from Apache and it does not do that. I wrote my own code to determine proxy and added that to Apache client code and it does not ask for connection approval.

Thanks for the help,
-Tony

Answer (score 0):

Disable the software firewall that is showing the dialog. The dialog isn't OkHttp; it's just a side effect from OkHttp using your network.

Comment: I will have to look into this. Most companies do not allow that to happen since that might be considered a high security risk. I am assuming you mean the Windows OS Firewall?

Comment: Is there some way to tell okhttp the proxy server name and port? I am using Java Web Start also. I am wondering if the security warning dialog is coming from that? Also I am using http2client from Okhttp. I want to keep using okhttp if I can.

Comment: I did run a test with windows firewall disabled and still got the warning dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue might have nothing to do with firewalls as I expected. I read there were issues with earlier versions of Java and even 8u25. I am using 32-bit 8u45 a security patch release. I installed 32-bit 8u60 EA and it seemed to have fixed the problem. So I am sure 32-bit 8u45 has the issue. Hopefully when 8u60 is released (soon I hope) it will still have the fix. I will check another laptop I have that works to see what version of java it is running.

Regards,
-Tony